# Separable $X^*$ Property

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. If $X^*$ is separable, then there exists $(f_n)_{n\geq1}\subset X^*$ such that $\|f_n\|_{X^*}=1$ for all $n$ and $\{f_n:n\geq1\}$ is dense in $\{f\in X^*:\|f\|=1\}$.

> In turn, why does this imply that there exists $(x_n)_{n\geq1}\subset X$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $f_n(x_n)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the norm?

Comment: @azarel Yes. So if I get it right the density is not used here and we also have the existence, for every $n$, of $(y_j)_{j\geq1}\subset X$ such that $\|y_j\|=1$ and $f_n(y_j)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $j$ ?

Comment: Formally there exists $y_n$ so that $\|y_n\|=1$ and $|f_n(y_n)|\geq \frac{1}{2}$ but multiplying by an scalar you can get $f_n(y_n)\geq\frac{1}{2}$